# What are the widest tires to be used in F1?

Tags: trivia, formula-1, auto-racing

Along with several aerodynamics and chassis weight regulation changes, the 2017 F1 season introduces wider tires.

- *2016 Front/Rear tire width*: 245mm / 325mm
- *2017 Front/Rear tire width*: 305mm / 405mm **(+25%)**

Is this the widest tire dimensions that a Formula One car has ever used?

Comment: VIsually the tyres used in the late 1970s appear wider than the ones for 2017 but I can't find any info re actual dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

After searching a bit, there is not much detail or a definite answer, but this *[Autosport article](http://www.autosport.com/news/report.php/id/119745)* says the 1992 tyre width was 420mm and the biggest until now.

But this other link of *[Tyre-Shopper](https://www.tyre-shopper.co.uk/blog/formula-one-tyres-2016)* says the same width was used in 2017.

This is the tyre used in 1992:

[image: 1992 formula One car with rear tyre]

Comment: The Tyre-Shopper article says there was a *proposal* to increase the rear tyres to 420mm. [In reality](https://www.formula1.com/en/championship/inside-f1/rules-regs/2017-season-changes.html), they were only increased to 405mm.